# Does cooldown reduction work on champions' innate passive abilities?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does cooldown reduction work on innate passives? For example, Le Blanc's Mirror Image, Garen's Perseverance or Anivia's Rebirth? If yes, on which passives does it work, and which does it not work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Champion Innate Abilities *can* scale (for instance, Vi's shield scales with health, Diana's bonus magic damage scales with ability power), but
**currently, there are no champion innate abilities that scale off of (or are reduced by) CDR .**

Any ability (innate or otherwise) that scales with CDR will use white numbers on the scaling variable.

Comment: Did you have Wiki or Riot employes source?

Comment: @iber of what, exactly? I'm familiar with the passives of the champions, and none are based around CDR.

Comment: I seek something written that all passives are not affected by cdr :)

Comment: @iber And that's not a statement that can be made. You have to consider each passive individually. None of the current 100+ passives are, but one could conceivably in the future.

Comment: But the question isn't, does it scale off of CDR, but rather, does CDR reduce the cooldown?  This wouldn't be shown in the tooltip just like it isn't shown for any other abilities

Comment: @RavenDreamer maybe this way - is there any passive that is affected by CDR at the moment?

Comment: @iber No. I will bold that part of my answer.